# A hard $n$-fold integral

Tags: time-complexity

Consider the $n$-fold integral 
$$
J = \int_{\theta_1 \in I_1, \theta_2 \in I_2 \ldots, \theta_n \in I_n} d\theta_n\ldots d\theta_2 d\theta_1
$$

whose intervals are defined by 
$$
\begin{align}
I_1 = [0,1] \\
I_i = [\max(c_i,\theta_{i-1}),1] , 2\leq i\leq n  
\end{align}
$$

and the $c_i \in [0,1]$ are predefined **rational** constants. Given a rational $v\in [0,1]$,

> is deciding if $J=v$ NP-hard?

Informally , each $\max$ in the lower limits of the intervals leads to a two-way split in evaluating the integral, and thus to $2^{n-1}$ integrals that sum to $J$.

Comment: I wonder if there are otherways to find the volume of this polytope.  Have you consider math.stackExchange?

Comment: I took a call on this question and posted a copy on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/135076/an-np-hard-n-fold-integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question received an answer on  [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135076/an-np-hard-n-fold-integral)  ; the integral can be computed in $O(n^2)$ time.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a special case of the following: given a convex polyhedron defined by a set of linear inequalities, compute its volume.  I believe that problem has been studied in the literature.

For instance, for related work on computing the volume of convex polyhedra/polytopes, see the following:

- [Algorithm for finding the volume of a convex polytope](https://mathoverflow.net/q/979)
- [Computing the Volume of a Convex Polytope Using Interval Arithmetic](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.53.5711&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- [Polytope volume computation](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1991-57-195/S0025-5718-1991-1079024-2/S0025-5718-1991-1079024-2.pdf)

There is probably lots more work out there that might be relevant, but maybe this gives you a start.  You might start by reading that work to see if there are any techniques you can adapt; and by doing a literature review with the above as an entry point into the literature.

Comment: Not to forget: The problem is #P complete as shown by Dyer and Frieze (1988).